# Accessing ViewController loaded using presentModalViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have the following code:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad{
    LoginViewController *lvc = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
    [lvc setDelegate:self];
    [self presentModalViewController:lvc animated:YES];
}
```

Is there a way to access the view that has currently been loaded without expanding lvc's scope (i.e. turn into an instance variable)...

Comment: You mean you want to access the variables in lvc ?

Comment: One thing, you will leak memory if you dont release the lvc after you present it.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it via:

```
self.modalViewController
```